# XLM design is not reflecting after run android studio

Tags: android

My XML Preview design before executing android studio.

[image]

After Executing android studio design is showing old design, I changed EditText name but still showing the same name and also added new button that also not reflecting after run my android app.

[image]

Below is my XML design:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.cnkonline.demo2.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Email"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Mobile"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />
```

Comment: Don't use @+id with layout_below and such properties. Use @id instead. Former is used only for setting the id of the element

Comment: But previous was warked correctly, recent I changed only names. @Sreejithtk

Comment: When I drag and drop from the list default only coming like that XML design . @Sreejithtk

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 2.0? If you are, then click the stop application before starting app again

Comment: I am using Android Studio 1.5.1. and I had stop previous run app also. @ShashankUdupa

Comment: @zahed, make `crean` and `rebuild` of your project

Comment: I did that also clean and rebuild then run. @VladimirMarkeev

Comment: You haven't closed the Relative view tag

Comment: I closed, but miss into above question, I dont know what to do and one more think, my other new app is also not display any UI. @ShashankUdupa

Comment: The plus(+) symbol means that this is a new resource created and added to R.java file. Since it is already declared  it could lead to problems when declaring it again and yes the drag and drop comes like that, no idea why.

Comment: Shall I Re-Install Android Studio. @Sreejithtk

Comment: No.. That is not the issue

Comment: I becoming mad. @Sreejithtk

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same xml file name in your setcontentview method in your corresponding java file? Other than that I don't see any problems in your code